# Plotting multiple datasets against dates on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotib/pandas to plot a variable (y-axis) as a function of date (x-axis). The simple code snippet below works great for one trace/set of data:

```
import datetime as dt

fig = plt.figure()

dates = grouping_data_for_profit_trace["date"]

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
y = grouping_data_for_profit_trace["variable"]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)

plt.show()
```

[image: One trace plot]

However, I want to plot several datasets on the same plot. If I put the code above into a loop and simply recalculate and plot x and y for each loop iteration/dataset i.e.

```
loop...

    #fig = plt.figure() - now commented out
    x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in dates]
    y = grouping_data_for_profit_trace["variable"]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xticks(rotation=30)
```

I start to see strange errors I don't understand e.g.

```
---> 53         plt.xticks(rotation=30)
.....
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Can anyone comment on why this is happening or offer a suggestion as to how 2 sets of data can be plotted against x axis dates on the same plot?

Comment: You're using Pandas I assume? What version?

Comment: Yes! - edited the question to reflect. I'm using python 2.7and pandas 0.18.1

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150972/plotting-dataframe-raises-error-of-ordinal-value-must-be-1) question/answer seems to suggest that there is a bug in that version of Pandas. You might want to upgrade your pandas version

Comment: Good find, David! I will try it now. Thanks!

Comment: The issue persists when I upgrade to pandas 0.20.3...any further thoughts?

Comment: The idea is, as usual, to provide a [mcve] of the issue. This way you make sure everyone is talking about the same thing as well as make it easy for potential solutions to acutally help you. Helping others help you is always a nice gesture. Very specifically I'm not sure if using `plt.xticks` is a requirement here. Do you need that line? Is the issue there when not using it? Is your question about rotating the ticks?

Comment: At the end it turns out that after creating a mcve myself, the issue is not even reproducible, i.e. the code runs fine in- and outside a loop. I would therefore vote to close this question.

Comment: Does it work if you don't rotate the xticks? i.e. if you comment out that line?